# Shoutcast Player doesn't work in two windows

Tags: wordpress, flash, media-player, shoutcast

Ok, My problem is:
I have a shoutcast player, the player is:
http://activeden.net/item/customizable-mp3-and-shoutcast-player/1393839

This is regullary flash player.

When the surfer enters the site is immediately listens player playing in the background. Whenever a user clicks on the "Listen separate window" player does not work in the new window and continues to go through the normal site. Only when the user closes the site and left the window that opens player starts.

The site is:
http://www.mizrahit.co.il/

In the top of the player you can Click on the text in black background and white color for oen in new window.

Comment: I thought it might be your SHOUTcast server configuration, as you can configure SHOUTcast/Icecast to only accept a single connection at a time from an IP address.  However, that does not seem to be the issue.